# CsvHelper not parsing correctly

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have the following CSV.

```
Org Defined ID,Username,FirstName,LastName,Attempt #,Attempt Start,Attempt End,Section #,Q #,Q Type,Q Title,Q Text,Bonus?,Difficulty,Answer,Answer Match,Score,Out Of
,testomalley,Test,O'Malley,1,2/3/2016 15:24,2/3/2016 15:28,,1,LA,Q(1) 1- 5 Part 1,"Scenario 1 for Questions 1 through 5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  Part 1 - Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem.",FALSE,1,Here is my answer o grader. Isn't it brilliant?,,0,2
```

Now here's my object I'm trying to convert it to:

```
public class Exam
{
    public int? OD_ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int AttemptNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime AttemptStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime AttemptEnd { get; set; }
    public int? SectionNo { get; set; }
    public int QuestionNo { get; set; }
    public string QuestionType { get; set; }
    public string QuestionTitle { get; set; }
    public string Questiontext { get; set; }
    public string Bonus { get; set; }
    public int Difficulty { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public string AnswerMatch { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public int OutOf { get; set; }
}
```

I have this map defined:

```
public sealed class ExamMap : CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvClassMap<Exam>
{
    public ExamMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.OD_ID).Name("Org Defined ID");
        Map(m => m.Username).Name("Username");
        Map(m => m.FirstName).Name("FirstName");
        Map(m => m.LastName).Name("LastName");
        Map(m => m.AttemptNo).Name("Attempt #");
        Map(m => m.AttemptStart).Name("Attempt Start");
        Map(m => m.AttemptEnd).Name("Attempt End");
        Map(m => m.SectionNo).Name("Section #");
        Map(m => m.QuestionNo).Name("Q #");
        Map(m => m.QuestionType).Name("Q Type");
        Map(m => m.QuestionTitle).Name("Q Title");
        Map(m => m.Questiontext).Name("Q Text");
        Map(m => m.Bonus).Name("Bonus?").TypeConverterOption(true, "TRUE").TypeConverterOption(false, "FALSE");
        Map(m => m.Difficulty).Name("Difficulty");
        Map(m => m.Answer).Name("Answer");
        Map(m => m.AnswerMatch).Name("Answer Match");
        Map(m => m.Score).Name("Score");
        Map(m => m.OutOf).Name("Out Of");
    }
}
```

and this TypeConversion option for my DateTime field:

```
var options = new CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterOptions
{
    //        2/3/2016 15:24
    Format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:nn", // also tried "g" with no success.
};
```

This is code to parse the CSV file:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    using (CsvReader csvread = new CsvReader(sr))
    {
        csvread.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
        csvread.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
        CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterOptionsFactory.AddOptions<DateTime>(options);

        List<Exam> Exams = csvread.GetRecords<Exam>().ToList();
        foreach (var rec in Exams) 
        {
          // Each record will be fetched and printed on the screen
          // checking values of rec here...
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how it is being parsed:
[image: Values]

Why is it not parsing the DateTime fields correctly and why are these properties not being filled?

QuestionNo
QuestionType
QuestionTitle
Questiontext
AnswerMatch
AttemptNo
OutOf

Comment: your datetime format is MM/dd/yyyy HH:nn. Should be "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm, with mm, not nn.

Comment: That did not change the result. Even changing it to "M/d/yyyy HH:mm" didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a method for DateTime parsing like this (you can even set a breakpoint now and modify the options):

```
Map(t => t.AttemptStart).Name("Attempt Start")
    .ConvertUsing(new Func<CsvHelper.ICsvReaderRow, DateTime>(r =>
        {
            DateTime dateTimeValue;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(r["Attempt Start"], null,
                System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out dateTimeValue))
            {
                return dateTimeValue;
            }

            return default(DateTime);
        }));
```

The missing fields may be errors based on the DateTime parsing issue. It looks correct at first sight.

Comment: Your variables show you should be using TryParseExact.

Comment: Tried this, too with same null results: `DateTime.TryParse(r["Attempt Start"], out dateTimeValue)`. In fact, adding that ConvertUsing caused the values to be set to null where before they were set to `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` I changed the dateTimeValue definition to this so I wouldn't get nulls: `DateTime dateTimeValue = DateTime.Now;` and `return dateTimeValue`

Comment: You are right, I fixed my code to parse the DateTime successfully based on your example (see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Na4CPM). It's strange it does not even reach your breakpoint. Can you maybe `.Ignore()` some properties and check the first one causing issues?

Comment: Still never stops at break point. I'm not even sure it is using the map because i added the `.Ignore` to all but the `Attempt Start` and got the same results with many of the other properties being filled. Is there a special way of telling it to use the map class, I don't see it in the docs?

Comment: I see this in the docs but am not sure what it means: "You need to register your class map in configuration"

Comment: Ok, I found it. `ExamMap ExamsMap = new ExamMap();                     csvread.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(ExamsMap);` That fixed everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to work fine for me. All I did was this.

```
csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<ExamMap>();
csv.GetRecords<Exam>().ToList().Dump();
```

I get all the fields you're missing showing up just fine too.

CsvHelper will parse all those types by default. You can add type converter options easier than that also, if you need to.

[TypeConverterOptions](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#mapping-type-converter-options)

Here is the full example from linqpad.

```
void Main()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Org Defined ID,Username,FirstName,LastName,Attempt #,Attempt Start,Attempt End,Section #,Q #,Q Type,Q Title,Q Text,Bonus?,Difficulty,Answer,Answer Match,Score,Out Of");
        writer.WriteLine(", testomalley, Test, O'Malley,1,2/3/2016 15:24,2/3/2016 15:28,,1,LA,Q(1) 1- 5 Part 1,\"Scenario 1 for Questions 1 through 5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  Part 1 - Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem.\",FALSE,1,Here is my answer o grader. Isn't it brilliant ?,, 0, 2");
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<ExamMap>();
        csv.GetRecords<Exam>().ToList().Dump();
    }
}

public class Exam
{
    public int? OD_ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int AttemptNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime AttemptStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime AttemptEnd { get; set; }
    public int? SectionNo { get; set; }
    public int QuestionNo { get; set; }
    public string QuestionType { get; set; }
    public string QuestionTitle { get; set; }
    public string Questiontext { get; set; }
    public string Bonus { get; set; }
    public int Difficulty { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public string AnswerMatch { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public int OutOf { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ExamMap : CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvClassMap<Exam>
{
    public ExamMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.OD_ID).Name("Org Defined ID");
        Map(m => m.Username).Name("Username");
        Map(m => m.FirstName).Name("FirstName");
        Map(m => m.LastName).Name("LastName");
        Map(m => m.AttemptNo).Name("Attempt #");
        Map(m => m.AttemptStart).Name("Attempt Start");
        Map(m => m.AttemptEnd).Name("Attempt End");
        Map(m => m.SectionNo).Name("Section #");
        Map(m => m.QuestionNo).Name("Q #");
        Map(m => m.QuestionType).Name("Q Type");
        Map(m => m.QuestionTitle).Name("Q Title");
        Map(m => m.Questiontext).Name("Q Text");
        Map(m => m.Bonus).Name("Bonus?").TypeConverterOption(true, "TRUE").TypeConverterOption(false, "FALSE");
        Map(m => m.Difficulty).Name("Difficulty");
        Map(m => m.Answer).Name("Answer");
        Map(m => m.AnswerMatch).Name("Answer Match");
        Map(m => m.Score).Name("Score");
        Map(m => m.OutOf).Name("Out Of");
    }
}
```

Comment: Josh, apparently you didn't read my last comment on @Scoregraphic's post. I did remedy the problem and posted a request to update your documentation as an issue on GitHub.